# Event not firing on RadioButtonList inside ListView

Tags: asp.net, .net, events

I attach OnSelectedIndexChanged event with RadioButtoList (that is inside  ListView)in  SlectedIndexChanged event of listview , when I run the program, click on RadioButton, there no event fire  even I implemented all code for this particular event firing. However there is no syntax or compilation error. Tell me what type of event I call against which either ListView or RadioButtonList?

.aspx Code:

```
<asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server"  >
<itemtemplate>
    <asp:RadioButtonList ID="radiobuttonlist4" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" Width="240px"  onselectedindexchanged="selected">
        <asp:ListItem Value="agree" ></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="disagree"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="strongagree"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="strongdisagree"></asp:ListItem>
    </asp:RadioButtonList>
</itemtemplate>
</listview>
```

Code Behind:

```
protected void selected(object sender, EventArgs e)
{    
    RadioButtonList listtt = (RadioButtonList)sender;       
    ListViewItem item = (ListViewItem)listtt.NamingContainer;

    RadioButtonList er = (RadioButtonList)item.FindControl("radiobuttonlist4");    
    er.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(handle);                    
}

public void handle(object sender, EventArgs e)
{            
    Label3.Text = "hjeje";        
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You OnSelectedIndexChanged is on the list view and not the radio button list.  Try moving the event attachment to the radio button list.

Answer (score 0):

in your `ListView`'s `ItemDataBound` method, you need to bind the `selected` event there.

```
var rdo = e.Row.FindControl("radiobuttonlist4") as RadioButton;
rdo.OnSelectedIndexChanged+= new EventHandler(selected);
```

Comment: but i am using listview instead  of gridview