# Radiobutton changed value doesnt update hiddenfield?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I've got a hidden field in an asp.net gridview like so:

```
 <asp:TemplateField>
      <ItemTemplate>
          <input type="hidden" value="0" id="hdnIsChanged" runat="server" />
      </ItemTemplate>
 </asp:TemplateField>
```

The hidden field is used so that if another field on my gridview is changed I can update the value of this hidden field with the value 1.  That way when I click a "Save" button I can loop through the rows of my gridview and only call my database update routine if and only if the hiddenField.Value = "1".

I set this field in the `rowdatabound` event of the gridview easily with something like this for a textbox:

```
    HtmlInputHidden hiddenField = (HtmlInputHidden)e.Row.FindControl("hdnIsChanged"); //get handle on hidden row isDirty
    TextBox notes = (TextBox)e.Row.FindControl("txtNotes"); //get notes

//assign onchange / onclick event handlers when something is changed set hidden field to 1
    notes.Attributes.Add("onchange", "document.getElementById('" + hiddenField.ClientID + "').value=1");
```

This works fine for textboxes and drop downs but I also have a radiobuttonlist in my grid.  When I change for instance 3 rows in my gridview by just selecting the radio button, it always ONLY updates 1.  It appears the hidden field doesnt get set correctly.  I thought I could set it correctly like this:

```
RadioButtonList rbl = (RadioButtonList)e.Row.FindControl("rbAnswer"); //get answer

                //assign onchange / onclick event handlers when something is changed set hidden field to 1
                  foreach(ListItem li in rbl.Items)
                    li.Attributes.Add("onclick", "document.getElementById('" + hiddenField.ClientID + "').value=1");
```

This doesn't appear to work and consider clicks for each radio button.  As I said if I update three rows by just clicking the radiobutton in each row and then click my save button it only calls the update routine once.  It appears the hidden field does not get the value 1.

Can anyone help?

### Edit

Just in case here is my entire grid view control:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="myPanel" runat="server" UpdateMode="Always" >
                     <ContentTemplate>
                    <asp:GridView ID="gvLineItems" runat="server" AllowSorting="True" 
                        AlternatingRowStyle-BackColor="#e5f1fa" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                        BackColor="#E8E8E8" CellPadding="4" DataKeyNames="ID" Font-Size="Small" 
                        GridLines="Horizontal" HeaderStyle-BackColor="#4B6C9E" 
                        HeaderStyle-ForeColor="White" ShowFooter="True" Width="700px" 
                             onrowdatabound="gvLineItems_RowDataBound" 
                             onrowcreated="gvLineItems_RowCreated">
                        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#E5F1FA" />
                        <Columns>
                            <asp:TemplateField>
                                 <ItemTemplate>
                                      <input type="hidden" value="0" id="hdnIsChanged" runat="server" />
                                 </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:TemplateField>
                                <HeaderTemplate>
                                    <asp:CheckBox ID="HeaderLevelCheckBox" runat="server" 
                                        onclick="toggleSelection(this);" ToolTip="Select / Deselect all rows?" />
                                </HeaderTemplate>
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:CheckBox ID="chkSelector" runat="server" onclick="ChangeRowColor(this)" 
                                        ToolTip="Select row?" />
                                </ItemTemplate>
                                <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" Width="1%" />
                                <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                            </asp:TemplateField>

                            <asp:TemplateField Visible="False">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblID" runat="server" style="display:none" 
                                        Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.ID") %>' Width=".05px"></asp:Label>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                                <ItemStyle Width="1%" />
                                <ControlStyle Width="0px" />
                                <HeaderStyle Width="0px" />
                            </asp:TemplateField>

                              <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="#">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblSortOrder" runat="server" 
                                        Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.SortOrder") %>'></asp:Label>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                                 <FooterStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                                 <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                                 <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                            </asp:TemplateField>

                             <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Validation">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblValidationItem" runat="server" ToolTip="Type of validation."
                                        Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.ValidationItem") %>'></asp:Label>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                                 <FooterStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                                 <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                                 <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                            </asp:TemplateField>

                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Test">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblTest" runat="server" ToolTip="Type of test."
                                        Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.Test") %>'></asp:Label>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                                <FooterStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                                <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                                <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                            </asp:TemplateField>

                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Method">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <table>
                                        <tbody>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td> <asp:Label ID="lblMethod" Font-Bold="true" runat="server" ToolTip="Method / Question"
                                        Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.Method") %>'></asp:Label></td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                            <td>
                                             <asp:Label ID="lblMethodNotes" CssClass="tiny" runat="server" ToolTip="Specifications / Notes"
                                        Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.MethodNotes") %>'></asp:Label>
                                            </td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                                <ControlStyle Width="250px" />
                                <FooterStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                                <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" Width="250px" />
                                <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" Width="250px" Wrap="True" />
                            </asp:TemplateField>

                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Answer">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                               <div id="dMainAnswer">
                                <asp:RadioButtonList ToolTip="Please provide an answer to the method." AutoPostBack="true" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" ID="rbAnswer" runat="server" SelectedValue='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.AnswerID")%>' OnSelectedIndexChanged="rbAnswer_SelectedIndexChanged">
                                    <asp:ListItem Text="Yes" Value="Yes" style="color:green;"></asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Text="No" Value="No" style="color:red;"></asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Text="N/A" Value="N/A"></asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="" Text="" style="display: none" />
                                </asp:RadioButtonList>
                                   <asp:Panel ID="pnlAnswer" runat="server" Visible="false">
                                       <div id="dMainAnswerResponsibleType">
                                            <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rbRespType" ToolTip="Select responsible contact type." runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" AutoPostBack="true" SelectedValue='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.ResponsiblePartyType")%>' OnSelectedIndexChanged="rbRespType_SelectedIndexChanged">
                                                <asp:ListItem Selected="True" Text="SE" Value="SE">SE</asp:ListItem>
                                                <asp:ListItem Text="Other" Value="Other">Other</asp:ListItem>
                                                <asp:ListItem Value="" Text="" style="display: none" />
                                            </asp:RadioButtonList>
                                        </div>
                                        <div id="dMainAnswerResponsible">
                                             <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlEmployees" runat="server" 
                                                DataSource="<%# GetEmployees() %>" SelectedValue='<%# Eval("SEContact") %>' DataTextField="FullName" Width="75px"
                                                DataValueField="FullName" 
                                                ToolTip="Select the SE responsible party.">
                                            </asp:DropDownList>
                                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtContact" Text='<%# Eval("ResponsiblePartyContact") %>' Width="75px" MaxLength="50" runat="server" ToolTip="Enter the responsible contact name." Visible="false"></asp:TextBox>
                                        </div>
                                   </asp:Panel>
                               </div>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Notes">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                               <asp:TextBox MaxLength="5000" runat="server" ToolTip="Enter any additional notes." ID="txtNotes" TextMode="MultiLine" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.Notes") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                                <ControlStyle Font-Names="Arial" />
                                <FooterStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                                <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                                <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                        </Columns>
                        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#4B6C9E" ForeColor="White" />
                    </asp:GridView>

                  <div style="width:100%;text-align:center;">
                    <asp:Label ID="lblLineItemMessage" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                    <asp:UpdateProgress AssociatedUpdatePanelID="myPanel" DisplayAfter="1" ID="udProgress" runat="server" Visible="True" DynamicLayout="True">
                        <ProgressTemplate>
                            <img style="border-style:none;" src="images/ajax-loader.gif" alt="loading" />
                        </ProgressTemplate>
                    </asp:UpdateProgress>
                </div>
                </ContentTemplate>
                <Triggers>
                    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="ddlTypes" />
                    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="ddlValidations" />
                    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="ddlTests" />
                    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="ddlJobs" />
                    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="rbMethod" />
                    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="TreeView1" />
                </Triggers>
                </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

I even tried some jquery to get an alert:

```
  $(function () {
            $("#<%=gvLineItems.ClientID %> input[type=radio]").click(function () {
                alert("hi");
            });
        });
```

But I dont think that is right because when I click a radio button I am not seeing any alert.  I also need to update the field `hdnIsChanged` the hiddenfield with the value 1 when a radio button item from the radiobuttonlist `rbAnswer` is clicked.  I am ok to do this in jquery but could use some help.  The hiddenfield hdnIsChanged and the radiobuttonlist rbAnswer are both inside an asp.net gridview.

Comment: Where is @Tim Schmelter when you need him the most :).

Comment: and the updated row is the one with the last radiobutton you clicked?

Comment: @RoboLover - No the updated row is the first one I have clicked.  If I have 20 rows and I click 1-19.  And I click the save button.  Only row 1 is updated.  I have debugged my code and it shows the hdnIsChanged hidden field having a value of 1 ONLY for row 1.

Comment: are you sure all the radiobuttons are rendered with a different id on the web page?

Comment: @RoboLover - yes they are in a gridview, for instance here is one: `//*[@id="MainContent_gvLineItems_rbAnswer_1_0_1"]`, and another one might be ..._1_0_2 and another one might be ...2_0_1 etc..each has a unique ID.

Comment: pinging @Tim Schmelter - is there any other way to do this.  Could I be the first person to have this issue?

Comment: do you get the alert with the first click to one of radiobuttons?

Comment: @RoboLover - yes as I said if I click on the 3 buttons, the first one is the only one that gets the event, if that event is an alert then yes its the first one that alerts...

Comment: I think you might need to set onselectedindexchanged events programmatically, it seems like your radiobuttons stay one on the page. check this link http://stackoverflow.com/a/10824215/647884

Comment: @RoboLover - My issue is not firing the OnSelectedIndexChanged event.  That fires fine for each click.  My issue is adding an attribute to each ListItem (Radiobutton) within a radiobuttonlist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally got it thanks to debugging through googles developers tool within the browser.
I noticed initially on my page (right click inspect element) every radio button within the radiobuttonlist for each row had an "onclick" attribute..Great so far.

The minute I clicked on a radiobutton, I have "AutoPostBack=true" for my radiobuttonlist, the minute I clicked on it, the only item that had the onclick attribute was for the row I clicked.  Every other row the attribute was gone.

The simple solution was in the `selectedindexchanged` event of the radiobuttonlist to loop through each row in the gridview and readd the attribute.

```
 foreach (GridViewRow row in gvLineItems.Rows)
            {
               HtmlInputHidden hiddenField = (HtmlInputHidden)row.FindControl("hdnIsChanged");
               RadioButtonList rbl2 = (RadioButtonList)row.FindControl("rbAnswer");

              foreach (ListItem li in rbl2.Items)
               {
                   li.Attributes.Add("onclick", "document.getElementById('" + hiddenField.ClientID + "').value=1");
               }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using jQuery?

```
<asp:GridView ID="grdViewLines" runat="server" CssClass="dirty-tracking-grid">
<Columns>
    <asp:TemplateField>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <input type="hidden" value="0" runat="server" row-id='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem") %>'  />
        </ItemTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:RadioButtonList runat="server" row-id='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem") %>' CssClass="dirty-tracking">
                <asp:ListItem runat="server" Text="Item1"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem runat="server" Text="Item2"></asp:ListItem>
            </asp:RadioButtonList>                    
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:TemplateField></asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $(".dirty-tracking :radio").click(function () {
        var rowId = $(this).closest("table").attr("row-id");
        $(".dirty-tracking-grid input[type=hidden,row-id=" + rowId).val(1);
    });
});
```

Comment: This is a radiobuttonlist inside of a gridview control so you cant reference it like that.

Comment: A radiobuttonlist renders radio buttons. jQuery cares not about RadioButtonLists, at the end of the day each item renders as: <input type='radio'...

Comment: Right but its still within a gridview.  Assume I have a asp.net gridview called gvLineItems and within this gridview I have a radiobuttonlist called rbAnswer.  my jquery is rubbish, how would I reference such a thing so that onclick it sets a hiddenField which is ALSO in my gridview...

Comment: Ah, right.  My apologies, I missed the hidden field as being part of the GridView.

Comment: its probably possible using .ClientID on the gridview which would return the correct row..but my jquery is not so good.  I posted my entire grid.  There has got to be a solution for this I am missing something very basic.  I think looping through each `ListItem` wont work though as I dont think you can assign attributes like `onclick` for a ListItem (one radio button).  I might be wrong though and that's why I posted on the best forum in the world!  I know @Tim Schmelter is really good when it comes to asp.net with js stuff so I am keeping my hopes alive.

Comment: Could I do something like this `$(function () {
            $("#<%=MainContent_gvLineItems.ClientID %> input[type=radio]").click(function () {
                $('#<%=hdnIsChanged.ClientID %>').val(1); 
            });
        });` I cant seem to handle how to get the hiddenField?

Comment: Nope doesnt seem to like that.

Comment: Have you tried putting `onclick="alert('Blah');"` into the ListItem tags in your markup to see if you can simply get an alert when you click each item?

Comment: aletrasg - as mentioned in the post this will alert for the first item clicked on, never any other item.  For instance if I do: `foreach(ListItem li in rbl.Items)
                    li.Attributes.Add("onclick", "alert('hi');");` It will alert only the first radiobuttonlist item clicked.

Comment: See my edited code, it is an unobtrusive approach. It works for me locally.

Comment: In your case you may need to use `DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.ID") %>` I was simply binding to a List<int> for testing so I did not need to use ID

Comment: I left a bit early today, I can give this a try tomorrow but I will be honest I don't like the looks of this.  It appears to use a dummy css class to get a handle in jquery..and Im not even sure what row-id is..its not a valid attribute of the tag so I just don't know about this solution.  I cant believe I'm the first with this problem?

Comment: I might have an idea, what I did not try to do is perform this on a radiobuttonlist ondatabound event.  Maybe the way I did it in code is a timing issue.  I think I will try this tomorrow, namely to add a DataBound event that will run upon the event then something to the effect of `RadioButtonList rbl = (RadioButtonList)sender; foreach(ListItem li in rbl.Items) li.attributes.add("onclick", "alert('hi');");` maybe that will work in the databound event.

Comment: I guess it should really be `data-rowid` so it is a true data-* attribute.  You can use the `<%=xx.ClientID` rather than the presented class approach.  I most often move my javascript to related .js files so that option then becomes unavailable.

Comment: Also a note on the "dummy class".  A class name need not be associated with css, that is only a part of its purpose.  Here I did not make it semantically usefull, but I was just whipping together a theoretical proof of concept. Class does not mean Css.